# Is it good idea to write query multiple time

Tags: php, mysql

I have accounts, posts and discussions tables.
When retrieve a post I also want to get discussions related to that post.
The table relationship is a post can have zero or more discussions.
I wrote the following query.

```
SELECT p.*,d._id, d.discussion, d.discussed_by  
FROM posts p, discussions d   
WHERE d.post_id = p._id
```

This query work but the result is as shown in the following.
From `_id` to `account_id` are from posts table. If I have 100 discussions about this post the result will have 100 duplicate data. How can I overcome this. My idea is get this post first time (first query) and get all discussions of this post (second query). How about that?

In php array form I want to get results in following format
post (1)  discussion (1), discussion (2), discussion (3)
But now my query return in the following result.
post (1)  discussion (1)
post (1)  discussion (2)
post (1)  discussion (3)
I am using PHP and mysql.[image: Result of the above query]

[image: Wanted result, is it possible or not?]

Is it possible or not?

Comment: You need to use left join query for this

Comment: The discussions themselves certainly aren't duplicate.

Comment: @Chetan Panchal How can I use? Will you please explain me?

Comment: @ChetanPanchal I don't think the join type is relevant here.  Show us your expected output.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  Yes, the discussions are not duplicate. But posts are duplicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP said a post can have zero or more discussions.

Comment: Show what output you actually want.  Don't leave us guessing.

Comment: I think this is a proper outlput

Comment: you have different types of discussion so

Comment: @ChetanPanchal Left join also gives him the same result. If the discussion count for any post is 1000 then the result would show the 1000 records with the full detail of the left side table. it will be the same. I think joining multiple table for this question is not a good way. In-spite us the two different query.

Comment: *My idea is get this post first time (first query) and get all discussions of this post (second query). How about that?* That's an excellent idea. Are we done?

Comment: @shmosel yes that's a good idea .

Comment: @shmosel Yes I did it. But actually I don't want to write twice for this result. Because I am worrying about performance. Writing two query will access database to 2 times . I think this may be slower than one query.

Comment: You don't have to query twice. You can de-dup the results in PHP. It's your choice.

Comment: @shmosel What is de-dup? Will you please explain me?

Comment: De-duplicate. Just run a single query and ignore the duplicate posts.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, I also tried this. But I do not want duplicate data in my result. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: You won't display duplicate data if you ignore the duplicates. Or you can run separate queries. Like I said, it's your choice. I don't know what else I can add.

Comment: @shmosel I see. I have only two way (de-dup as you said and write separate query) I tried both way and worked perfectly. But I want to do is write one query and no duplicate data. I think it is impossible. Thank you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I edited my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132866/discussion-between-nyein-chan-and-shmosel).

Answer (score 1):

One option to get the result you want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` on the discussions sharing the same post ID.  This would result in a comma separated list of discussions for that thread.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.discussion, 'NA')
FROM posts t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT _id, GROUP_CONCAT(discussion) AS discussion
    FROM discussions
    GROUP BY _id
) t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2._id
```

Comment: There is no data from discussions table in the result. Do I need to change something in your query.?

Comment: I updated my answer, just do an additional join to `discussions`.  I recommend _not_ using `.*` to select, but rather spelling out each column.  This will let you handle nulls more easily.

Comment: Your answer work well but the result is same as mine in question.

Comment: Once again, you never showed us the output you want.  If you want to _aggregate_ records in the `discussions` table, then you need to specify what you want to aggregate.  So...what output do you really want?  Spell it out clearly please.

Comment: I want all data from discussion but only one data from posts. As an example I want to get all discussions of [post_1] but I want to get post data only once. I hope you understand my comment. I cannot explain clearly anymore because of my English skill.

Comment: My answer is as good as you will get I think.  You need to aggregate the `discussions` table, but this mean that _everything_ from this table must be an aggregate.  Again, show sample output, as what you are saying is not clear.

Comment: I added a new figure to my question.